# DartEditor: Pub build crashing

Tags: dart, dart-editor

After clicking "Pub build" menu item in an empty project with sample code, a window pops up: "dart.exe is not working any more". The editor doesn't crash actually, despite of this notification. The console output is:

```
--- 11:47:17 Running pub build ... ---
Pub build failed, [-1073741819] You don't have a lockfile, so we need to generate that:
Resolving dependencies...Error WSAIoctl failed: 10022
....
Downloading browser 0.10.0+1...
Error WSAIoctl failed: 10022
```

Nothing gets built (operation gets aborted automatically). Anyone having this issue too? Any solution? Is it a bug?

Specs: Win 7, x86, DartEditor 1.2.0

Comment: I have never seen this error before. The error message looks like a network issue. Do you use a proxy or do you have your Dart project stored on a network drive? Is this your first attempt or did it already work but now you get an error?

Comment: No proxy. Project locally saved. My first attempt with Dart.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Can you try to run `pub upgrade` and `pub build` from command line from within your Dart package directory (where the `pubspec.yaml` file is).

Comment: Sorry for the noob comment, but it doesn't work. `Command "pub" not found`. My working directory was the one where the `.yaml` file is. Maybe I misconfigured something, system PATH or ..?

Comment: I don't know if there are manual steps necessary when installing Darteditor on Windows (I use Linux) but there is obviously a PATH missing. Can you add a path to the `dart-sdk\bin` subdirectory of the darteditor installation directory and try again?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the DartEditor

Comment: Yes. Even after updating the issue is still there. Dear Google / Dart Folks, can you please fix it? I would like so much to start coding with Dart, which is a great tool, but I can't do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem appeared to me after an automatic update from 1.3.6. to 1.4.0.

A complete reinstall of Dart + Editor from the ZIP file solved the problem.

Comment: What helped for me, was running Dart Editor as administrator.